# Spatial Join with WHILE condition (in QGIS)

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I'm new to QGIS and have a Spatial Join task to solve.
I have many polygon features (layer 1, green in picture below) distributed accross all Germany, representing renewable energy plants. These must be matched with point features (layer 2, purple in picture below) that represent demographic data. The criteria for the joints are:

- Point features from layer 2 are matched to a unique polygon (no duplicates).
- Point features from layer 2 must be within a certain distance from features of layer 1. Doesn't have to be necessarily the closest one. Can also be randomly done.
- Point features from layer 2 are matched with the points from layer 2 until a certain criteria is met (sum of field values from matched features in layer 1 is equal to a field value of layer 1)

Any idea how to solve this or what tools to use?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use QGIS expressions with overlay functions. Use it e.g. with Field calculator to create an attribute containing the id of the joined feature on another layer.

On the point layer, get the id of the nearest polygon, but with a maximum distance of 7000:

```
overlay_nearest(
    'poly',  -- name of the polygon layer
    poly_id,  -- name of the attribute you want to get
    max_distance:=7000 -- change the value of max_distance
)[0]
```

*Points that are max. 7000 m away from a polygon are labeled with the id of the closest polygon:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This part I managed to solve. But can I add a WHILE condition to the overlay function? The tricky part is doing the joins while a certain criteria is still met. At the same time, it has to be done for all point features, so it should somehow be done one after the other.

Comment: This is possible using the optional filter and limit arguments of `overlay_nearest ()` function, see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest , combining it with aggregate functions. Probably a bit more context or even better sharing (sample) data could help giving advice for your very use case.